# Writing to Socket Java doesn't work properly

Tags: java, sockets, networking, communication, bufferedwriter

So I've been given a Server.jar file, which runs a tic tac toe server.
What I'm supposed to do now is to connect to this server via a TCP Socket and
send HTTP requests (e.g. "GET /game/ HTTP/1.1"), and receive the tictactoe field.

Now I seem to be able to connect to the server, and also send the first request.
My second out.write however seems to be either ignored or causes an exception.
I don't understand why... The Server doesn't seem to respond to the second message/request either.

```
 Socket sock;
        try 
        {
            sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",8080);
            System.out.println("Connection established at "+sock.toString());
            Scanner in = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());//Step 2.

            PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(),true);//Step 2.
            out.println("GET /game/ HTTP/1.1\nHost: 127.0.0.1\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n");        
            String test ="";            
            while( (in.hasNext())== true)       
            {        
                test = test + in.nextLine();        
            }

            System.out.println(test);
            //This one is ignored somehow.
            out.println("GET /game/gamenumber HTTP/1.1\nHost: 127.0.0.1\n\n");


            while( (in.hasNext())== true)       
            {        
                test = test + in.nextLine();        
            }



            System.out.println(test);

            out.close();
            sock.close();    




        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
             System.out.println("Failed");
             e.printStackTrace();


        }
```

Note: I don't have direct access to the Servers Source Code, and the use of HTTPURLCONNECTION is not allowed.

Comment: ' or causes an exception' - so does it cause an exception or not? If so, please post the stacktrace (and please show your `catch` block...

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Comment: You should use a `Scanner` and a `PrintWriter`, it's much easier to deal with. (Or even the HttpURLConnection class)

Comment: Nope, I have to do it without HTTP URL Connection Class...

Comment: Is your server reachable with a web browser?

Comment: It is not. I mean I can try to connect to it, and the server will print "no method found".

Comment: You made the server along with this client? If that is the case, you might want to test the client with a  working server, and the server with a working client, otherwise you'll have to deal with 2 applications possibly not doing their job right. Given the error, I'd say the server is closing the connection after the first wrie, so the second one fails. (Or is the first that fails?)

Comment: I have not written the Server.
And the first request goes through.
It just seems that the second write to the output of the socket is ignored. The Server does only react to my first request, and sends a valid answer. The second write although done exactly the same, with a valid request just doesnt go through...

UPDATED FIRST POST.

Comment: Do you know the protocol you are using? maybe, the problem is that you are sending something like `\n\n` that the server doesn't like or maybe there is nothing wrong with your code, and the server is just buggy

Answer (score 1):

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

This is usually caused by writing to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. As you aren't sending a content-length header the server has closed the connection after the first request.

And the line terminator in HTTP is \r\n, not \n.

You need to take a good look at the HTTP 1.1 protocol RFC. Or use HttpURLConnection, which will take care of it completely for you. Unless this is homework and you are required to implement HTTP 1.1 yourself, which seems bizarre, it is also bizarre to deny you the use of the one class in the JDK that is actually designed for precisely this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding out.flush() after each println.

Comment: (1) Adding flushes doesn't solve a 'socket write error'. (2) If that was the problem it wouldn't work at all. (3) He is using PrintWriter in auto-flush mode so an additional flush() won't do anything useful. -1